# Not getting GCM on sendbird android v3

Tags: sendbird

I've upgraded to sendbird's android v3 library and am unable to get GCM notification event after registering serverkey on dahboard, following all steps on registering my GCM id from the app.

For the demo app provided on github, I am able to receive it only after the app is killed forcefully.

any directions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can receive GCM only sendbird is in disconnected state. This can be done you call SendBird.disconnect().

By the way, the latest SDK supports automatic background checking so you don't have to call SendBird.disconnect() to receive GCM.

https://github.com/smilefam/SendBird-SDK-Android/tree/master/com/sendbird/sdk/sendbird-android-sdk/3.0.2

Please upgrade SDK and try it.

Thanks.